# jenkins credentials menu is not appearing in sidebar

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins version `2.249.3`. In the sidebar menu of jenkins home page, `credentials` menu is not appearing.

[image]

Where can I access this `credentials` menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post login to Jenkins, you have to navigate to Users > your user profile > Credentials or the below given URL.

[Credentials Page](https://jenkins.com/user/admin/credentials)

[image: Jenkins User Credentials Page]